# When I open full screen a Youtube video on my page it shows the content inside the html

Tags: html, youtube

I am trying to embed a video from youtube onto my main page, everything it's good, but when I fullscreen the video instead of seeing the video only, I see the video + the pictures and text that I wrote in my main page... overwriting my video..... I'll show a picture

This is my simple HTML:

      
  [Picture with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO2S7.jpg)

Comment: THE HTML I USED , it's not too long:      <div class="container">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/n8UUqaoWG80" class="video" width="50%" height="200px" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
     </div>

Answer (score 0):

And what if you add a z-index to the video?

something like

```
.container iframe {
    z-index: 10
}
```

Comment: nothing, it's exactly the same, I've tried with every index from 1-10 and position: absolute/relative